# Clojure read from a file and add to JSON object

Tags: clojure

I have a simple text file which contains simple email strings such as:

```
email1@example.com
email2@example.com
email3@example.com
email4@example.com
```

I want to be able to return the contents of this file as a json response through my `REST` api which is a simple `GET` request.

Is there a way I can read the file line by line (I can do that) and append to a JSON object such that I can easily render the contents on a webpage.

```
{
    "emails": [
        "email1@example.com",
        "email2@example.com",
        "email3@example.com",
        "email4@example.com"
    ]
}
```

I want my `REST` API to look like:

```
(GET "/emails" [] {
    "emails": [
        "email1@example.com",
        "email2@example.com",
        "email3@example.com",
        "email4@example.com"
    ]
})
```

but I want to render the JSON upon request as the file can be modified.

Comment: Did you define the JSON object itself in your Clojure code? I mean, in terms of Clojure maps/vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution using the [Chesire library](https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire)

```
(GET "/emails" []
    (generate-string {:emails (clojure.string/split-lines (slurp "/path/to/file"))} {:pretty true}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
(GET "/emails" []
     (clojure.pprint/cl-format nil
                               "{\"emails\": [~{~S~^,~}]}"
                               (clojure.string/split-lines (slurp "/path/to/addresses.txt"))))
```

Comment: Thats almost what im after however is puts the `,` inside quotes as well so that the result is: `{:emails ["chris.edwards@intilery.com" "," "chris.edwards@intilery.com" "," ... `